# Como fazer uma fila de Promises em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promises, fila

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de fazer uma fila de **Promises em JavaScript**, de forma que a Promise que entrou só execute após a resolução da Promise anterior.

Exemplo:

```
var queue = [Promise1, Promise2];
queue.push(Promise3);
```

Nesse caso eu preciso que a `Promise2` aguarde a execução da `Promise1` e a `Promise3` aguarde a execução da `Promise2` para ser executada.

Na real eu preciso fazer essa fila para salvar dados em uma requisição e se eu não salvar na ordem que foi feita a solicitação os dados ficam bagunçados pois um resultado depende da resposta do outro.

Se puderem me ajudar ficarei grato!

Vou tentar explicar melhor.

Eu lanço um requisição para criar um registro com uma nota...porém esse registro é composto por 4 notas no total...a próxima nota para este registro é um update...o que acontece é que o lançamento de notas pode ser tão rápido que ao enviar a requisição de criar o registro não da tempo de receber o id criado para que a próxima seja um update, dessa forma eu acabo com dois registros criados sendo que deveria ser um create e depois um update.

Comment: Se uma *promise* depende do resultado da anterior, como você consegue instanciá-la sem o resultado que necessita? Pois como ela depende do resultado da anterior, ao meu ver você só conseguiria instanciá-la no momento em que *promise* anterior já tivesse resolvida.

Comment: E você não pode enviar as 4 notas na mesma requisição?

Comment: Infelizmente eu só tenho o front para trabalhar, não tenho acesso para alterar o funcionamento do back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá muito obrigado pela ajuda...

Com a ajuda deste repositório, ([angular-queue](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-queue)) eu fiz uma implementação de uma fila que faz o que eu estava precisando, se quiserem dar uma olhada no exemplo do código que fiz no Plunker ([promise-queue](https://plnkr.co/edit/zZWfkqdC7sabKbFSKxSp?p=preview)).

De qualquer forma muito obrigado e espero que eu possa ajudar mais alguém com isso.

Answer (score 2):

Se o callback do método [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining) retornar uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) é feito o encadeamento, então basta retornar a `Promise` da nova requisição e seguir encadeando `then()`.

Exemplo simples:

```js
// Retorna um Promise
function wait(seconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(seconds + " segundos se passaram...")
        }, seconds * 1000)
    })
}

wait(3)
  .then(msg => {
    console.log(msg)  // resultado de wait(3)
    return wait(1)
  }).then(msg => {
    console.log(msg)  // resultado de wait(1)
    return wait(2)
  }).then(msg => {
    console.log(msg)  // resultado de wait(2)
    return wait(3)
  }).then(msg => {
    console.log(msg)  // resultado de wait(3)
  }).finally(() => {
    console.log("fim...")
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Rafael,

Se entendi bem o seu questionamento, recomendo-lhe a utilizar a biblioteca no [link](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Abaixo consta um exemplo, qual possivelmente é sua resposta:

```
return Q.all([
    eventualAdd(2, 2),
    eventualAdd(10, 20)
]);
```

Evite o máximo possível, a menos se for um trabalho acadêmico, reinventar a roda. Espero ter colaborado para a solução do seu questionamento.

Tenha uma excelente tarde.